# How to disable Arrayformula calculate column names

Tags: google-sheets, multiple-columns, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to apply a formula to an entire column in sheets that is being populated from a form. It uses many rows (for example MT till QP), however, if it comes to the column: OR it doesn't work because it thinks it becomes an OR function. (so it is error-free till column OQ)

I've used $ in column names with no success

```
=arrayformula(query('Formulierreacties 1'!A1:RA; "Select " & 
 join(","; SUBSTITUEREN(ADRES(1; KOLOM(A:G); 4); "1"; "")) & ", " & 
 join(","; SUBSTITUEREN(ADRES(1; KOLOM(MT:QP); 4); "1"; "")) & " where G = 6002"))
```

> Error: #WAARDE!

Comment: Copy sheet:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uk2toJTMBj4Rn0eNxEI2nnr6ygl5lB1t5Pm-uxRnuQY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

you will need to escape **OR** column like **`OR`**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY('Formulierreacties 1'!A1:RA; 
 "select "&JOIN(","; SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1; COLUMN(A:G); 4); 1; ))&","&
  JOIN(","; SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1; COLUMN('Formulierreacties 1'!MT:QP); 4); 1; ); "OR"; "`OR`"))&"
  where G = 6002"; 1))
```

[image: 0]